# Angular2: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to install bootstrap using npm in Angular2 with this command

> npm install --save ng2-bootstrap

But I get following error and warning in console

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@0.3.0
+-- ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@^1.9.11

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or   architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of   webpack@^1.9.11 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/forms@2.0.0-rc.6 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI?

Comment: yes I'm using Angular CLI

Comment: With the latest webpack version? Beta version 13 I think it is? There's an open issue on github about this where you get unmet peer dependencies while installing the CLI. Not sure if they might be connected.

Comment: @rish check package.json from my EDIT answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your application to angular2 RC6 version.

Follow these steps-

1. Update @angular version to **2.0.0-rc.6** in package.json [Refer package.json here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files)
2. clean your node_modules folder and then run npm install.

See if this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

This is how my package.json looks like for angular2 RC6 and ng2-bootstrap 1.1.1 with angular-cli

```
{
  "name": "angular2-rc6-cli-ng2bootstrap-8-sep",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx for response, now I get  **UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-server@^2.0.0-rc.6**

Comment: same, is there a solution?

Comment: @h345k34cr check package.json from my EDIT answer.